# US Chase bank: "please confirm your residency status to avoid tax withholding"

Tags: united-states, taxes, banking

I'm an international student in California.
I received a letter from Chase asking for filled forms about residency status. They provided empty forms including W-8BEN, W-8BEN-E and W-9. I remember I filled W-8BEN and mailed it back to Chase. How can I check the status?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer service issue. The first step is to call the bank branch or the point of contact mentioned in the letter.

Comment: This looks like a legit question to me. Maybe it needs more edits - "I'm an international student in California. For tax purposes, when I need to forms about residency status, W8, W9, etc, what is my status?" - I've lost faith in relying on answers from anyone at a local bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a W-8BEN. The student needs to call Chase who would have received it and applied the tax withholding. The only answer is "Call Chase".